# trying to send form data to whatsapp from website

Tags: html, reactjs, express, twilio

I created one website here i created a form when user fill the form data and click on submit button i want to send form data to whatsapp for that i am using twilio but twilio is only free for one day if i want to send form data to whatsapp regularly it is asking me some amount so is there any other software which is freely available to send form data to whatsapp without taking money

I tried to send form data to whatsapp using twilio and i am getting form data in whatsapp also but if i want to get form data from website regularly means it is asking me to pay money in twilio

what i am expecting is to please tell me is there any software available to send form data to whatsapp without paying money

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There might be something someone could recommend but you need to be precise as what tech are you using.

What Im quite sure of is to get the most reliable service and an api that works well, you'll have to get a payed plan.

A quick google search and I found this, https://fonoster.com/
The free version is quite limited but its there.